# How can I create an ACL like only author can edit his post?

Tags: symfony, acl

I think this is a common requirement eg. "How can I create an ACL like only author can edit his post?". In Symfony 2, how will I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little complicated answer for a short question.  You should be a little more precise.

1. Enable ACL
2. Create roles/user
3. Create posts with connected user
4. Check rights when editing posts

Check out the cookbook. It has a large section about ACL's. And please, be more precise for evntual future questions. This is too vague to be answered.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html

Answer (score 0):

Incase that's not clear enough for some:

Have a look on this Blogpost about [Symfony2 and ACLs](http://rryter.blogspot.com/2012/02/symfony2-and-acls.html)